# How can I use css 'ids' in combination with server controls in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, css

My designer created a stylesheet that makes heavy uses of id's. Example:

```
<div id="globalheader">
<ul id="globalnav">....
```

css:

```
#globalheader { width: 715px; height: 100px; margin: 18px auto; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 20; z-index: 9998; }
#globalheader #globalnav { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#globalheader #globalnav li { display: inline; }
```

This doesn't display correctly anymore as soon I change one of the div elements to 'runat=server' because this will cause the ClientID to change. How can I solve this?

-Edoode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem that I don't think is solvable without post generation workarounds, some of them being...

- Add class attributes to the html elements and change the style declarations to .globalheader
- Leave the html elements as they are and do a find and replace in the stylesheet (the new id names should have a consistent prefix e.g. #ctl00_globalheader)

Comment: Thank you. Nested classes were indeed the way to go.